# Log in to Windows from a Python service?

Tags: python, windows, authentication

I'm theory crafting a Python service which will manipulate domain joined machines into running tests as part of a suite. Details of requirements

- We must be logged in as a domain user, and we must not have the automatic login enabled
- We need to reboot machines a few times, so it's a requirement for this to be sustainable

I'm wondering if it's possible to, from a Python service, somehow convince Windows to log us in? Presumably a Python service runs in Session0, as does Microsoft's Hardware Certification Kit? If that's capable of doing it, Python should also be (so far as I can see).

Any suggestions most welcome, I've got a suspicion there's a cheeky Windows API call that does this, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a way to do it from a Windows service (written in C++) and presumably the ctypes library will permit me to use it.

Simple as using LogonUser from Win32API so far as I can see. Yet to actually set up and test it but it does seem to be exactly what I need. The difficulty being that session0 can only be accessed once logged in or via some remote debugging, so getting something like this working is no easy feat.